# Shortcut in Adobe Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, cs6, typesetting

How to create a keyboard shortcut like if you type a paragraph and need to insert a symbol like this â, cause our language mostly like using some symbols like that. How to create a keyboard shortcut so you don't have to search again on Glyphs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are keyboard shortcuts for **[diacritics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic)**.. ñ, é, å, ç, à, ö...

I'd suggest you merely learn the shortcuts for these. 
It's not really an InDesign thing. It's generally built into the OS keyboard structure.

For Windows, you can check this list: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-to-add-language-accent-marks-in-word-3801b103-6a8d-42a5-b8ba-fdc3774cfc76

For the Mac: [https://www.reed.edu/cis/help/diacritics.html#:~:text=To%20type%20diacritics%20in%20a,%2B%20c%20(or%20C)](https://www.reed.edu/cis/help/diacritics.html#:%7E:text=To%20type%20diacritics%20in%20a,%2B%20c%20(or%20C)).

<sub>(In case of link rot, merely do an internet search for "[how to input diacritics](https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20input%20diacritics&ei=AwDcYMvNIdWBqtsP8PmRYA&oq=how%20to%20input%20diacritics&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsAM6CAgAEAgQDRAeOgcIABANEIsDOggIABCGAxCLAzoHCCEQChCLA0oECEEYAFCbJ1jzLWCvMGgAcAF4AIABvQKIAZkKkgEHMC44LjAuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQi4AQLAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiL29j5zr7xAhXVgGoFHfB8BAwQ4dUDCA4&uact=5)". Many relevant links will be presented.)</sub>

---

Above being posted...

If you *really* want to use the Glyphs panel in InDesign you can choose the `Show Options` item from the **Glyph Panel Menu**...

[image]

The **Glyph Panel** will then show `Recently Used` glyphs. So, you don't have to repeatedly find the same glyph if you are using it often.

[image]